# Restricting 'Users' in Laravel while still allowing everyone to edit their own 'User'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still learning Laravel & best practices.

I have a user system, so that you can create & update users through the UserController. Only admins should be able to access users & manipulate them. So I've created the following route:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController')->before('role:admin');
```

All looks good and works fine. I've got a filter that checks that the logged in user is an admin before they can access anything to do with users.

Here's where I'm getting confused. A user who logs in and is not an admin should still be able to edit their own information (email, password, username). I've setup a new form using the same form partial I have setup for editing users as all the fields are the same, and I thought i'd be able to process the form using the same form method so as not to duplicate the processing, which is identical:

```
{{Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'route'=>['user.update', $user->id]])}}
```

Except, because my user isn't an admin, they're getting pushed back to a 403 message instead of it processing the script.

How do I make an exception for a user to edit their own info, without loosing the admin restrictions on the UsersController?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy solution is to create an `AccountController` with different access restrictions. Any common processing done between `UsersController` and `AccountController` can be moved to the model.

Comment: okay, so if i do that and move the edit process to the accountcontroller does that mean if a user edits the form to try and edit a different userid, that they can succeed?

Comment: Well in the account controller you would just update the user that matches the logged in user.

Comment: I'm surprised this was selected as the acepted answer. @TH1981 Looks like bad advice to me, not DRY.